# how i can navigate user to another page from viewmodel

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, mvvm, xamarin.forms, asp.net-authorization

how i can navigate user to dashboard page after i got Access token and user successfully logged in or error messege when user entred wrong username or password

here is my login viewmodel

```
using RoyalSales.Views;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using RoyalSalesAPI.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.Res;
using RoyalSales.Helpers;

namespace RoyalSales.ViewModels
{
    class LoginViewModel
    {
        private APIServices _APIServices = new APIServices();

        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public String Message { get; set; }
        public ICommand Logincommand => new Command(async () =>
{
var accesssToken = await _APIServices.LoginAsync(Username, Password);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accesssToken))
{
Message = "login succeed";

Settings.Username = Username;

Settings.Password = Password;

Settings.AccessToken = accesssToken;
// here i want navigate user to dashboard page 
}
else
{
Message = "wrong username or password";
// here i want show message dialoge to tell user theres an wrong username or 
password 

                                                          }
                                                      });
        public ICommand LogOutcommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command( () =>
                {


                        Settings.AccessToken = null;

                });
            }
        }



        public LoginViewModel()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.Username))
            {
                Username = Settings.Username;
                Password = Settings.Password;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is  my loginpage.cs

```
using Javax.Security.Auth;
using RoyalSales.Views;
using Android.Provider;
using RoyalSalesAPI.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using RoyalSales.ViewModels;
using RoyalSales.Helpers;
using Settings = RoyalSales.Helpers.Settings;

namespace RoyalSales
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Login : ContentPage
    {
        public APIServices aPIServices = new APIServices();
        private string accessToken = Settings.AccessToken.ToString();
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);


        }

        private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



        }
    }
}
```

here is my loginpage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="RoyalSales.Login"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:RoyalSales.ViewModels;assembly=RoyalSales"
    Title="login page"
    BackgroundColor="#F38906">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:LoginViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout
            Padding="20"
            Orientation="Vertical"
            Spacing="30">
            <BoxView HeightRequest="20" />
            <Image
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Source="almotaheda.png"
                WidthRequest="175" />
            <Label
                FontSize="Large"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Text="slogn"
                TextColor="White" />
            <Frame BackgroundColor="#FBD7AC" HasShadow="False">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="10">
                    <Entry
                        x:Name="UserNameEntry"
                        HeightRequest="40"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        Placeholder="username"
                        PlaceholderColor="#F38906"
                        Text="{Binding Username}"
                        TextColor="Black" />
                    <Entry
                        x:Name="PasswordEntry"
                        HeightRequest="40"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        IsPassword="True"
                        Placeholder="Password"
                        PlaceholderColor="#F38906"
                        Text="{Binding Password}"
                        TextColor="Black" />

                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Label
                FontSize="20"
                Text="{Binding Message}"
                TextColor="#FFFFFF" />
            <Button
                BackgroundColor="White"
                Command="{Binding Logincommand}"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                FontSize="20"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Text="login"
                TextColor="#F38906" 
                Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
            <BoxView HeightRequest="20" />

        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

plese help my to navigate the user to dashboard page if successfuly logged in or error message if wrong username or password

Comment: Normally the way to do this is when you send the user to the login page, you attach a query parameter like this: `login?returnurl=someUrl`. Then once you log the user in, you send the user to the url in the query parameter. However, from your question it is not clear if you want to do this in a web app or what. In a web app, that is what you would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PushAsync` or `PushModalAsync` after setting the `AccessToken`

For example:

```
await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new dashboardPage(), true);
```

In order to display an Alert from viewmodel you can use:

```
await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Login message here", "Dismiss");
```

Comment: thanks alot for answer i will mark it as the best answer , can you tell me how i can inform user wrong username or password

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question.  The View Model has no knowledge of the views, so you can't use the *PushAsync* because you don't have the type information about the view.